# Can I create a new XML file that copies and auto updates an existing XML?

Tags: php, xml

I have found a XML file through google search that will help me for a simple project I am doing.
The problem is that I do not want to fetch the file but to create a new one on my server that copies and auto updates from the other. I tried to save it to my hard disc but it does not update.

I know that there is a way to do it because I have seen it but I don't have any clue how. I guess they created a "createxml.php" file that does what it does...

Any ideas or examples? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to pull in a remote XML file, do something with it and then save it on your hard drive?

In that case use [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://url.com/file.xml');

// Do something

file_put_contents('c:\file.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

If you want this script to run regularly then run it from a cron job.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes exactly this! Thanks! I set up a cron job so that the data are auto updated in a regular basis right? Alternatively, I have to refresh the page to do so ?

Comment: Exactly, slaving the script to cron is easily the better than manually refreshing.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have a last small question. The remote xml file is updated when the user or cron job visits a "reloadxml.php" file ( on the remote server). So my XML files is not updated unless I visit that file. Is there anything to do about that ?

Comment: You could use the curl library to call the remote script first from your local script I suppose.

Comment: @AdamWouldn't it be just as easy to do file_get_contents() since you aren't parsing any xml? The simplexml adds overhead that really isn't needed..
@mikey if you do a `file_get_contents('reloadxml.php');` that will mimic a visit to that file and after that you can do the actual request with `$xml = blablal`

Comment: @gnur This is very true, but I was not sure from his original question if he needed to parse/modify the xml in any way, so I assumed that he would want this functionality. But if not, of course, not using simpleXML is always a nice option!